# Отфильтровать без изменения создания нового массива

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно отфильтровать массив без возвращения нового массива. При использования filter или new Set возращается новый массив. Мне же необходимо, чтобы вернулся исходный массив, но с уже отфильтрованными значениями.
Необходимо отфильтровать `i!=={id: 1, name: "Sasha"}`

```
let arr = [{id: 1, name: "Sasha"}, {id: 2, name: "Ivan"}, {id: 1, name: "Sasha"}, {id: 6, name: "Ivan"}]
```

В результате должен вернуться отфильтрованный массив `arr`.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  {id: 1, name: "Sasha"}, 
  {id: 2, name: "Ivan"}, 
  {id: 1, name: "Sasha"}, 
  {id: 6, name: "Ivan"}
];

let ids = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  ids.has(arr[i].id)? arr.splice(i--, 1) : ids.add(arr[i].id);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Я наверное не совсем корректно выразился. У меня множество дублирующихся элементов(не только {id: 2, name: "Ivan"} )  разными id. И я хочу оставить только уникальный элементы

Comment: @AzetX Приведите пример входных данных (включающий все варианты) и ожидаемого результата.

Comment: У моего приложения вот какая логика: 
При клике на чекбокс в пустой массив добавляется продукт.
if(event.target.checked === true){
      productsBasket.push(product)
  } else{
}

Comment: @AzetX Это очень интересная логика, но это не ответ на мою просьбу.

Comment: Пардон. У моего приложения вот какая логика: 
При клике на чекбокс в пустой массив добавляется продукт, при условии что чекбокс===true, а если чекбокс===false, то необходимо удалять элемент из массива. Но возникла такая ситуация, что при клике на чекбокс(в не зависимости от состояние true или false) продукты добавляются в исходный массив. И получаются дубли.
И вот я хочу сделать так, что если чекбокс===false, то фильтровать исходный массив с дублями

Comment: let basketProduct = {{id: 1, name: 'apple'}, {id: 4, name: 'bannanas}, {id: 5, name: 'milk'}, {id: 4, name: 'bannanas}, {id: 1, name: 'apple'}, {id: 5, name: 'milk'}, {id:8, name: 'mandarines' }, {id: '7', name: 'pork'}, {id: 35, name: 'bear'}, {id: 8, name: {mandarines}}